# ido-mode breaks docker-tramp completion in minibuffer, and opens wrong files

Tags: tramp, ido, ido-find-file

Somehow the following minimal emacs config breaks docker-tramp. Completion in the mini-buffer does not work for `/docker:`, nor the container ids/names like `/docker:43893ad331df`, and once you type out the full tramp string like: `/docker:43893ad331df/` completion then suggests files from the host fs where emacs is running, not from the docker container fs, and if you type out the path to a file that exists in both fs' then it will be opened on the host fs not the container fs, and a file that only exists on the container fs will not be found at all.

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat "~/.emacs.d/" (file-name-as-directory "elpa")))

(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-verbose 9)
(require 'docker-tramp)

(defvar ido-dont-ignore-buffer-names '("*scratch*" "*Occur*"))

(defun ido-ignore-most-star-buffers (name)
  (and
   (string-match-p "^*" name)
   (not (member name ido-dont-ignore-buffer-names))))

(defun bind-ido-keys ()
  "Keybindings for ido mode."
  (define-key ido-completion-map "\C-n" 'ido-toggle-ignore))
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook #'bind-ido-keys)

(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-buffers 'ido-ignore-most-star-buffers)
```

Any idea what is going on, and how to fix it?

Edit: The issue went away with emacs 27.1. No idea why.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't narrow this down even more? I doubt the keyboard shortcut is what is causing the problem, for example.

Comment: The init code you provided worked for me (Linux)  - I was actually surprised to see my containers autocompleted for me.  File completion using Ido worked as well. Is your user able to execute `docker ps` without `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, my user can execute docker ps without sudo. If I comment out the ido-stuff then the tramp stuff works.